# Converting a register of unsigned-int16 to Ascii text

Tags: python, integer, ascii

Do have a register of unsigned-int16...the do represent ASCII..

```
[18281, 26465, 25193, 29765, 29800, 25970, 28261, 29745, 12081, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

text shown above should be translated to

```
"GigabitEthernet1/1"
```

Question is how to do the conversion. There are some solutions out there like. Python preferred of course

```
decoded = OrderedDict([
        ('string', decoder.decode_string(len(strng))),....
```

but they do require a length...and i do only want the text nothing else...

Answer (score 1):

A naive implementation would be:

```
>>> "".join(chr(i//256)+chr(i%256) for i in my_int16_list)
'GigabitEthernet1/1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

or if you want to exclude `0`s:

```
>>> "".join(chr(i//256)+chr(i%256) for i in my_int16_list if i > 0)
'GigabitEthernet1/1'
```